# Closing my ModalWindow object from within the Pane I assign to it

Tags: javafx

I've got a class called ModalWindow with a number of methods, the important ones here being:

```
show();

hide();

getContent();

setContent(Pane p);
```

When I create an instance of ModalWindow, I setContent(...); using a predetermined Pane object (one that is generated AFTER creation of the ModalWindow instance), then call show();. The hide(); method, while publicly accessible, is usually called from within the pre-generated Pane - I do this by using another method called (something like)

```
getPane(ModalWindow mW);
```

I do this so that I can access the hide(); function from within the Pane object (in my case my Pane usually contains a button used to close the ModalWindow, I do this by using

```
closeButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> mW.hide());
```

So, right now, most of my instances of ModalWindow look like this:

```
ModalWindow mW = new ModalWindow();
mW.setContent(getPane(mW));
mW.show(); // ModalWindow usually closed from within itself
```

What I'm wondering is: is there a way to use reflection (or something of that nature) to access the ModalWindow object that the Pane is being contained in (without having to generate the Pane object AFTER creation of the ModalWindow instance)?

Here's a full example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModalWindow mW = new ModalWindow();
        mW.setContent(PaneHolder.getPane(mW));
        mW.show();
    }
}

public class ModalWindow {

    StackPane centeringPane = new StackPane();
    private BooleanProperty showing = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public ModalWindow() {
        centeringPane.setOpacity(0);
        centeringPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public ModalWindow(Pane content) {
        centeringPane.setOpacity(0);
        centeringPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setContent(content);
    }

    public void show() {
        centeringPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hide() {
        centeringPane.setVisible(false);
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return showing.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty showingProperty() {
        return showing;
    }

    public void setShowing(boolean showing) {
        this.showing.set(showing);
    }

    public Pane getContent() {
        return (Pane) centeringPane.getChildren().get(0);
    }

    public void setContent(Pane content) {
        centeringPane.getChildren().clear();
        centeringPane.getChildren().add(content);
    }
}
public class PaneHolder {
    Pane getPane(ModalWindow mW) {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setOnAction(event -> mW.hide()); // I need the reference to mW here
        p.getChildren.add(closeButton);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, no, there is no way for an object to discover other objects that hold references to it (which is, I think, what you're trying to do). (And how do you know for certain there is only one such `ModalWindow` anyway?) Perhaps you can post some of the actual code?

Comment: @James_D I've added a full example, but I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify it something like this:

```
public class ModalWindow {

    StackPane centeringPane = new StackPane();

    // is this supposed to be bound to centeringPane.visibleProperty() somehow?
    private BooleanProperty showing = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private PaneHolder content ;

    public ModalWindow() {
        centeringPane.setOpacity(0);
        centeringPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public ModalWindow(PaneHolder content) {
        centeringPane.setOpacity(0);
        centeringPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setContent(content);
    }

    public void show() {
        centeringPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hide() {
        centeringPane.setVisible(false);
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return showing.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty showingProperty() {
        return showing;
    }

    public void setShowing(boolean showing) {
        this.showing.set(showing);
    }

    public PaneHolder getContent() {
        return content ;
    }

    public void setContent(PaneHolder content) {
        content.setModalWindow(this);
        centeringPane.getChildren().clear();
        centeringPane.getChildren().add(content.getPane());
    }
}
```

```
public class PaneHolder {

    private final Pane pane ;
    private ModalWindow mw ;

    public PaneHolder() {
        pane = new Pane();
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setOnAction(event -> mw.hide()); 
        p.getChildren.add(closeButton);
        return p;
    }

    public Pane getPane() {
        return pane ;
    }

    void setModalWindow(ModalWindow mw) {
        this.mw = mw ;
    }
}
```

And then you can do things like:

```
PaneHolder paneHolder = new PaneHolder();
ModalWindow mw = new ModalWindow(paneHolder);
```

and the close button will work with no additional code.

This isn't completely robust, etc; you probably want to think a little more about the lifecycle of these objects (e.g. perhaps you want to enforce that a `PaneHolder` can't be set as the content of a `ModalWindow` if it's already the content of another one, etc), but it should give you the idea.

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow. Thank you very much for your help.